# What is the main causes of kurento media server load

Tags: amazon-web-services, webrtc, kurento

I want to know that what is the main causes of kurento media server load.
And how can i solved it.Because my application is run on the c3 large machine.

**Problem**
 only 17 user connect with my application video conference than audio is not reached some peoples.

Comment: Usually, the cause of high load in a Kurento Media Server instance is due to transcoding or mixing of audio/video.

Comment: I think, jitsi-meet is the solution of this problem?

Comment: The difference with Jitsi (or Janus, or others) is that the media is not transcoded, so it doesn't require as much load.  See https://webrtc.ventures/2017/11/a-guide-to-webrtc-media-servers-open-source-options/ for a list of media server options, https://testrtc.com/sessions-kurento-server/ for info on Kurento load.

Answer (score 0):

The main CPU load comes from video frame encoding and decoding, especially in high resolution conference. So maybe have two ways to relieve it.

1. Choose low resolution conference.
2. Choose a video conference that supports sfu mode. This mode just routes video stream from one side to other sides.
3. Or choose a more efficient conference system